# Android: How to download a .png file using Async and set it to ImageView?

Tags: android, png, android-asynctask

I've got the URL of a .png image, that needs to be downloaded and set as a source of an ImageView. I'm a beginner so far, so there are a few things I don't understand:
1) Where do I store the file?
2) How do I set it to the ImageView in java code?
3) How to correctly override the AsyncTask methods?

Thanks in advance, will highly appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure you can explicity build a png from a download. However, here is what I use to download images and display them into Imageviews :

First, you download the image :

```
protected static byte[] imageByter(Context ctx, String strurl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlContactIcon + strurl);
        InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int bytesRead;
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        return output.toByteArray();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then, create a BitMap and associate it to the Imageview :

```
bytes = imagebyter(this, mUrl);
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
yourImageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

And that's it.

**EDIT**
Actually, you can save the file by doing this :

```
File file = new File(fileName);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(imagebyter(this, mUrl));
fos.close();
```

Comment: It raises an exception for me 
Exception of type 'Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException' was thrown.

Answer (score 5):

You can explicity build a png from a download.

```
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

`100` is your compression (PNG's are generally lossless so 100%)

`out` is your FileOutputStream to the file you want to save the png to.